# phpMyAdmin config file macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mamp, macos-sierra

I have recently installed MAMP and phpMyAdmin on my laptop which is currently running macOS Sierra. I have followed various online tutorials on how to configure phpMyAdmin but the one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to save a configuration.

From what I read I'm supposed to create a folder named `config` in the root folder of phpMyAdmin. I did just that and I also gave the folder full permisions for user group and others just to be safe. However, it didn't work and I still find myself having to reconfigure phpMyAdmin every time I restart my computer. I also tried to change the ownership of the folder in question but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you also found [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/) tutorial? It seems pretty detailed on how to correctly setup the config folder and stuff. Wouldn't know too much of it myself though.. sorry.

Comment: This was the first one I found actually. The only difference between what I did and what the tutorial does is that I used MAMP instead of using the built-in Apache server.